# How to import and use/run a C++ dll into another C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I've created a C# application. Within this application I would like to use/run a C++ API from another project(the API is written in macro coding). I tried import the dll of that C++ project and tried to call a functions which belongs to that API. The problem is that it throws "unable to find method" error.

How can I run a C++ project in a C# project?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C++ API in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689957/using-c-api-in-c-sharp) and probably tons of others (this just happened to show up in the "Related" questions list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a native DLL as a reference to a managed project. You have 3 main options:

1. Make the native functions available with p/invoke.
2. Expose the native code through COM.
3. Compile the native code as a managed C++ assembly.

For any serious amount of code, option 3 is the most productive and effective approach.

Answer (score 1):

If by "running", you mean a separate process:

Use the class `System.Diagnostics.Process`  available in .NET:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
myProcess.Start();
```

Else, if you mean using a dll developed in C++, you can use `Platform Invoke Services`:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    //First param is of course either in your PATH, or an absolute path:
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint="puts", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int PutString(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        PutString("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

Comment: functions in msvcrt.dll use cdecl calling convention

Comment: And that is irrelevant to my example. As far as I can tell he is working in C# and not in assembly.

Comment: No, it is relevant. Your DllImport attributes need to have CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl added.

Comment: Oh, I took for granted it used the default `CallingConvention.Winapi` since the [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) for the example doesn't explicitly state anything about calling conventions.

Comment: It's a bit different because it's a C runtime. But it certainly does  use cdecl. +1 for your edit.

Comment: Oh well, it's good to know if I ever need to use anything in there, thank you for pointing it out!